# How to store data after app closure and then retrieve it again on initialization?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a todo app that dislays a list of user input tasks via listview builder. Everything works fine until the user restarts or closes the app , due to which all the Tasks are lost . **Is there anyway to prevent state removal or save the state so that the items are not lost?**

The Listview.builder is given below :

```
ListView.builder(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 100),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    itemCount: items.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFFe0e2d4),
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100.0)),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(22, 15, 50, 9),
        height: _heightMap[index] != false ? 80 : 0,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onDoubleTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _heightMap[index] = !(_heightMap[index] ?? true);
            });

            Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 600), () {
              setState(() {
                _heightMap[index] = !(_heightMap[index] ?? false);
                items.removeAt(index);
                print(items);
                print(_heightMap);
              });
            });
          },
          child: Card(
            color: Color(0xFFe0e2d4),
            elevation: 0,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                  width: 63,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 20.0,
                      height: 20.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _heightMap[index] =
                            !(_heightMap[index] ?? true);
                      });

                      Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 600), () {
                        setState(() {
                          _heightMap[index] =
                              !(_heightMap[index] ?? false);
                          items.removeAt(index);
                          print(items);
                          print(_heightMap);
                        });
                      });
                    },
                    elevation: 0,
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    shape: CircleBorder(
                      side: BorderSide(
                        width: 2.3,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 7, 0)),
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text(
                      items[index],
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 21,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Save your task to a JSON/text file or use shared preferences

Comment: Could you please explain how I could use shared preferences? Isn't it used to keep a user logged in.

Comment: yes, it is used to keep a user logged in which just a use case. But the main function of it to store the last state of data even after the app is closed (removed from recent apps). So  you can store your whole to-do list data as a map and read again on init of app

Comment: Okay I shall look into it , thank you :)

Comment: I have added an answer hope that solves the problems

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is store your data in some local database and when the app opens read your data from it. You can use [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) or [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) as well, which ever suits you.

Comment: I tried using firebase but kept getting a lot errors , so I decided to look for a way to store the data on the users device

Comment: If you want to store data online then firebase is a good option and if you want to store data on a user device then I suggest you use hive or sqflite as these two store data locally.

Answer (score 1):

Use Shared Preferences to store the to-do list data.

https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

---

### A function to save the list in Sharedpreference:

create an update list items function which will run after the user deletes or add a new item to the To-Do list.

```
_updateitems(List items)async{
  String str ='';
   str='[';
  
  int c=0;
  items.forEach( (e){
    if (c==items.length-1){
      str=str+'"$e"';
    }
    else{
      str=str+'"$e",';
    }
    c+=1;
    
  });  
  str = str + ']';
  print(str);
  // creating the shared preferences instance
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  // set value
  prefs.setString('todoJson', str);
}
```

this is an `async` function so will be updating the to-do items list as and when the user updates the list and storing it in the `sharedPreferences` as a string as a `JSON` object.

### Now reading the string on app startup:

We will be reading the string as a `JSON` object on app initialisation. Remember to call this function in `initState(){}` of your main app.

Import this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

Read Function:

```
readToDoList()async{
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String str = prefs.getString('todoJson') ?? 0;
  
  //This items should be define in a global scope outside the function with List datatype
  items = json.decode(string);
  print(items);
  
}
```

This will read the `JSON` object from the `sharedPreferences` and return you the last stored/State of the to-do list data.

---

**Note: Since there is the use of `async` function while reading the data on app init, it is a better option to use a `FutureBuilder` and give the `readToDoList` as the future and show a `circularProgressIndiacator` while the app is asynchronously reading data.*

Hope this helps.